# Assign a random color to points based on categorical property in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I want to create a layer "my_layer" of points from a geojson file "my_file.geojson". Each point should be colored based on a categorical property "my_property". However, categories are many, so I can not specify a color for each category. I want to assign a random color to each category.

```
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'my_layer',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data':  'my_file.geojson'},
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
    'circle-color': { 'property': 'my_property', 
    'type': 'categorical',
    'stops': ?}
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add color in your property section in `geojson` file by 
parsing the `geojson` features and assigning them property color using HashSet to avoid duplicate color in java or python.

and then use

```
["get","color"]
```

in circle-color property.